# Javascript animate image, slide up bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an sliding image and I have a problem it it. If you do fast mouseover over the images multiple times and then you get the mouse outside pics it still animates. Somehow it records and plays the animation even after you are not with mouse over it.
Here is my code and [link](http://websoftit.ro/site_twingo/index.html) to check it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.col-md-4,.col-xs-4').hover( 
    function () {
        $(this).find('#hoverpic').animate({ "top": "-=330px" }, "normal" );
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('#hoverpic').animate({ "top": "+=330px" }, "normal" );
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `.stop()`

```
   function () {
        $(this).find('#hoverpic').stop().animate({ "top": "-=330px" }, "normal" );
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find('#hoverpic').stop().animate({ "top": "+=330px" }, "normal" );
    });
```

if `.stop()` doesn't work well enough

you can try with `.stop(true)` or `.stop(true, true)`

http://api.jquery.com/stop

Comment: stop works, but after few rollovers it bugs, you can check the link to see how it's with stop

Answer (score 1):

you should put a check for

```
if( $(elem).is(':animated') ) {...}
```

in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.col-md-4,.col-xs-4').hover( 
    function () {
        if(!$(this).is(':animated'))
        $(this).find('#hoverpic').animate({ "top": "-=330px" }, "normal" );
    },
    function () {
        if($(this).is(':animated'))
        $(this).find('#hoverpic').animate({ "top": "+=330px" }, "normal" );
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a class while it's animating.
Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.col-md-4,.col-xs-4').hover( 
    function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('animate')) {
            $(this).addClass('animate');
            $(this).find('#hoverpic').animate({ "top": "-=330px" }, "normal" );
        }
    },
    function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('animate')) {
            $(this).find('#hoverpic').animate({ "top": "+=330px" }, "normal", function() { $(this).removeClass('animate'); } );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a simple change (see commented code) if you want to avoid the jumping image when hovering out before the animation finishes:

```
$('.col-md-4,.col-xs-4').hover(
function () {
    $(this).find('#hoverpic').stop().animate(
    { "top": "0px" } //WAS -=330px
    , "normal" );
},
function () {
    $(this).find('#hoverpic').stop().animate({ 
    "top": "330px" //WAS +=330px
    }, "normal" );
});
```